# How to create a dataframe using a list of dictionaries that also consist of lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of dictionaries that also consist of lists and would like to create a dataframe using this list. For example, the data looks like this:

```
lst = [{'France': [[12548, ABC], [45681, DFG], [45684, HJK]]},
 {'USA': [[84921, HJK], [28917, KLESA]]},
 {'Japan':[[38292, ASF], [48902, DSJ]]}]
```

And this is the dataframe I'm trying to create

```
Country      Amount    Code
France       12548     ABC
France       45681     DFG
France       45684     HJK
USA          84921     HJK
USA          28917     KLESA
Japan        38292     ASF
Japan        48902     DSJ
```

As you can see, the keys became column values of the country column and the numbers and the strings became the amount and code columns. I thought I could use something like the following, but it's not working.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the code values at first be inside quotes?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to transform the data into a format that Pandas can read.

##### Original data

```py
data = [
    {"France": [[12548, "ABC"], [45681, "DFG"], [45684, "HJK"]]},
    {"USA": [[84921, "HJK"], [28917, "KLESA"]]},
    {"Japan": [[38292, "ASF"], [48902, "DSJ"]]},
]
```

##### Transforming the data

```py
new_data = []
for country_data in data:
    for country, values in country_data.items():
        new_data += [{"Country": country, "Amount": amt, "Code": code} for amt, code in values]
```

##### Create the dataframe

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(new_data)
```

##### Ouput

```
  Country  Amount   Code
0  France   12548    ABC
1  France   45681    DFG
2  France   45684    HJK
3     USA   84921    HJK
4     USA   28917  KLESA
5   Japan   38292    ASF
6   Japan   48902    DSJ
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(elem) for elem in list])
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values)).stack()
df = df.reset_index(level=[0], drop=True).to_frame(name = 'vals')
df = pd.DataFrame(df["vals"].to_list(),index= df.index, columns=['Amount', 'Code']).sort_index()
print(df)
```

output:

```
        Amount   Code
France   12548    ABC
USA      84921    HJK
Japan    38292    ASF
France   45681    DFG
USA      28917  KLESA
Japan    48902    DSJ
France   45684    HJK
```

Answer (score 1):

Use nested list comprehension for flatten data and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
lst = [
    {"France": [[12548, "ABC"], [45681, "DFG"], [45684, "HJK"]]},
    {"USA": [[84921, "HJK"], [28917, "KLESA"]]},
    {"Japan": [[38292, "ASF"], [48902, "DSJ"]]},
]

L = [(country, *x) for country_data in lst 
                   for country, values in country_data.items() 
                   for x in values]

df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['Country','Amount','Code'])
print (df)
  Country  Amount   Code
0  France   12548    ABC
1  France   45681    DFG
2  France   45684    HJK
3     USA   84921    HJK
4     USA   28917  KLESA
5   Japan   38292    ASF
6   Japan   48902    DSJ
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a new dictionary that combines the individual dicts into one, before concatenating the dataframes:

```py
new_dict = {}
for ent in lst:
    for key, value in ent.items():
        new_dict[key] = pd.DataFrame(value, columns = ['Amount', 'Code'])

pd.concat(new_dict, names=['Country']).droplevel(1).reset_index()

  Country  Amount   Code
0  France   12548    ABC
1  France   45681    DFG
2  France   45684    HJK
3     USA   84921    HJK
4     USA   28917  KLESA
5   Japan   38292    ASF
6   Japan   48902    DSJ
```